# Azure Request Queue Limit Exceeded

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I need to run a report which needs to extract information from a WCF service which is running as an Azure Web App.  Unfortunately, there are about 6000 requests I need to run and they MUST be run individually.

When I throw the entire book at the service, I get

```
ASP.NET rejected this request because the queue limit was exceeded.
```

I can't find any information which says what the Request Queue Limit is per pricing tier.

Does anyone know what the limits are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an Azure limit, the queue length is IIS/CPU/Memory bound.  See [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/644891/asp-net-rejected-this-request-because-the-queue-limit-was-exceeded) for a brief explanation. You should consider having your app queue/throttle the requests with a mechanism like Azure queues.

Comment: That article points out that there is indeed a queue limit.  It describes that the reason for that queue filling up and getting exceeded is because the cpu is not keeping up.  But, there is still a fixed limit.  This is what I am looking for.  Is it 500, 1000 or 5000 queue times?  Azure queues sounds like a good idea but I would still need the queue limit in order to set how many items Azure Queue should handle concurrently.

Comment: Azure web apps run on IIS, the limit depends on the resources available - `available memory * processor * 10 / total number of application pool` - which in most web apps, you won't be able to determine, due to shared resources.

Comment: As an experiment, change your App Service Plan that the web app runs under to P3 (Premium pricing tier) with 4 core and 7GB RAM and see if you hit a limit.  You always have the option to auto-scale based on resource consumption.